# Git: Trouble doing push: error: src refspec remotes/origin/iteration1 matches more than one

Tags: git, windows-xp, tortoisegit

I'm using `TortoiseGit` on `Windows XP`.  I've commited all my changes and now I'm trying to push them to a branch of the remote repository.  The remote repository branch is named "remotes/origin/iteration1".  However, when I try and push by right clicking within the root directory, selecting "TortoiseGit", then "Push".  I enter these values on the following screen:

```
Branch
    Local: remotes/origin/iteration1
    Remote: iteration1
Destination:
    Remote: iteration1
```

Here is the error I get when I do this.  How do I push my changes?

> git.exe push --progress  "origin" remotes/origin/iteration1:iteration1
>
> error: src refspec remotes/origin/iteration1 matches more than one.
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@mycogit/zzz_pplus.git'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with tortoisegit but `remotes/origin/iteration1` as the source is certainly wrong since it's a remote branch. If your local branch is named `iteration1`, enter this in that field.

The actual git comment you want to execute is `git push origin iteration1:iteration1`